# Why does the Java Compiler not inline these calls in a single if clause?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, javac, bytecode

I have been pulled into a performance investigation of a code that is similar to the below:

```java
private void someMethod(String id) {
   boolean isHidden = someList.contains(id);
   boolean isDisabled = this.checkIfDisabled(id);

   if (isHidden && isDisabled) {
     // Do something here
   }
}
```

When I started investigating it, I was hoping that the compiled version would look like this:

```java
private void someMethod(String id) {
   if (someList.contains(id) && this.checkIfDisabled(id)) {
     // Do something here
   }
}
```

However, to my surprise, the compiled version looks exactly like the first one, with the local variables, which causes the method in `isDisabled` to always be called, and that's where the performance problem is in.

My solution was to inline it myself, so the method now short circuits at `isHidden`, but it left me wondering: Why isn't the Java Compiler smart enough in this case to inline these calls for me? Does it really need to have the local variables in place?

Thank you :)

Comment: It's not the compiler's job to do optimization of any kind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First: the java compiler (`javac`) does almost no optimizations, that job is almost entirely done by the JVM itself at runtime.

Second: optimizations like that can only be done when there is no observable difference in behaviour of the optimized code vs. the un-optimized code.

Since we don't know (and the compiler presumably also doesn't know) if `checkIfDisabled` has any observable side-effects, it has to assume that it might. Therefore even when the return value of that method is known to not be needed, the call to the method can't be optimized away.

There is, however an *option* for this kind of optimization to be done **at runtime**: If the body (or bodies, due to polymorphism) of the `checkIfDisabled` method is simple enough then it's quite possible that the *runtime* **can** actually optimize away that code, if it recognizes that the calls never have a side-effect (but I don't know if any JVM actually does this specific kind of optimization).

But that optimization is only possible at a point where there is definite information about what `checkIfDisabled` does. And due to the dynamic class-loading nature of Java that basically means it's *almost never* during compile time.

Generally speaking, while some minor optimizations *could* possibly be done during compile time, the range of possible optimizations is much larger at runtime (due to the much increased amount of information about the code available), so the Java designers decided to put basically all optimization effort into the runtime part of the system.

Comment: One addition: even if the code at runtime happens to be identical to the compile time version, the potential presence of tools like debuggers still mandates that the compiler does not eliminate methods calls which are required by the formal specification. Only the runtime optimizer which knows that there are no side effects and no breakpoints, etc. can eliminate such a method call.

Answer (score 0):

The most-obvious solution to this problem is simply to **rewrite the code** something like this:

```
if (someList.contains(id)) {
  if (this.checkIfDisabled(id)) {
    // do something here
```

If, in your *human* estimation of the problem, one test is likely to mean that the other test does not need to be performed at all, then simply *"write it that way."*

Comment: This is completely missing the question. There is no difference between `if(someList.contains(id) && this.checkIfDisabled(id)) { … }` and `if (someList.contains(id)) { if (this.checkIfDisabled(id)) { … } }`; both constructs produce exactly the same bytecode. Whether your suggestion is an improvement, is debatable, but as said, this is not even remotely the topic of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Java compiler optimizations are tricky. Most optimizations are done at runtime by the JIT compiler. There are several levels of optimizations, the maximum number of optimizations by default will be made after 5000 method invocations. But it is rather problematic to see which optimizations are applied, since JIT compile the code directly into the platform's native code